# How to read a file from JMETER in node.js and index into elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, jmeter, multer

I am  using node.js to index a file into elasticsearch.
i am trying to give input as a file from jmeter? i.e.., as **req.file**
but it giving output as undefined.
can anyone specify the better solution?

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: '10.96.82.98:9200',
  log: 'trace'
});
http.createServer(app).listen(1000);

//indexing a document

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/post/:index/:type/:id/', function(req, res){
var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile('inpu.file',req.file);
client.index({
index: req.params.index,
type: req.params.type,
 id: req.params.id,
 body:JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'/inpu.file'))
},function (error, response) {
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response);
  });
});
```

i am using this code

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: please look into my code@Paul